# Using PushBots for android push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am trying to use pushbot for android push notification. it works fine if when the application is running. But for instance if the application is not running and a push notification arrives, it starts the app and then crashes it. Any suggestion to the cause of this problem?

Comment: Please include the code you are using in the client side.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure

1. you've copied PushBots.jar file into libraries folder of your android project.
2. Extended the Application Class, and initialized PushBots in its onCreate method, check out steps 6,7 **[click here](https://pushbots.com/developer/tutorial#/android/new/step/5)** for more details

Here's a sample code:

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.app.Application;


public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Pushbots.init(this, "","");
}
}
```