# PushBot recieving push notifications crashes app when its not running

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I'm a beginner to Java and android programming and I have followed the tutorials for PushBot to creating a working app. However the app crashes when receiving a push notification if it's not running in the foreground. So I have had a little search on here and the pushbots website and found about extending the class to the application. The problem is I cannot get this method working by extending by application and not the activity. I now been staring at it so long I can't see the wood from the trees and it's probably a really simple fix I get an error on the public class Myapplication line and can't compile (it must be defined in its on file apparently) :

heres the code :

```
package co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest;

import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {     

private String SENDER_ID = "Oh know you dont :) My sender id here ";
private String PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID = "oh know you dont :) my app id here";

@Override    
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();        
    Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID,PUSHBOTS_APPLICATION_ID);     }  }
```

Here is the Mainifest file where I expect it's all going horribly wrong lol.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> 
<permission android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />     
<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest.MyApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

    >

    <activity
        android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>    
            <action android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest.MESSAGE" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBMsg"/>
        <activity android:name="com.pushbots.push.PBListener"/>
        <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action     android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category    android:name="co.uk.mypchealth.pushbottest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.MsgReceiver" />
        <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
        <service android:name="org.openudid.OpenUDID_service" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.openudid.GETUDID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

These are the pages I've been looking at :

https://pushbots.com/developer/tutorial#/android/new/step/5

[PushBots App Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344477/pushbots-app-crash)

[Using PushBots for android push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853064/using-pushbots-for-android-push-notification)

Comment: Please provide your whole code.

Answer (score 2):

Check the video tutorial on youtube (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faop6vBBe3E)

I'll quote here too:

> Please make sure you've copied PushBots.jar file into libraries folder
>   of your android project. And also make sure you extended Application
>   Class, and initialized PushBots in its onCreate method, check out
>   steps 6,7 in this link for more details
>   https://pushbots.com/developer/tutorial#/android/existing/step/4

step 6,7

here's a sample code:

```
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
@Override public void onCreate() { >super.onCreate();
Pushbots.init(this, "",""); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Pushbots developer offers you a new way that is equal to configure initilization.Please check out that side [pushbotdeveloping](https://pushbots.com/developer/gcm) it will give  route you step by step.I had solved my problem via that way.